# Using Android content provider with GridView to browse large number of images

Tags: android, gridview, android-contentprovider, android-cursoradapter

I need to implement an Android application which allows users to browse a large number of images (10000) stored on a server.

I can use REST style HTTP calls to get the information about images e.g. GET http://uri...?itemsstart=n&itemscount=m which returns me the names and locations of images.

I have a content provider with a cursor adapter which I can use to get this information. I’d like to hook this up to a `GridView` to allow for scrolling of images.

There are several examples here and elsewhere on the web about using similar scenario for a small fixed number of images **:** you just use  `setAdapter` on the `GridView` or `ListView` and it will do its magic when user initiates a database query via menu etc.

In my case, user should be able to scroll through images continuously while the app is loading them in “chunks” in the background.

My question is how and when to initiate a new query to get a new “chunk” of images in such a way that my `CursorAdapter/GridView` combination will be updated for continuous scrolling?
I would appreciate some advice about this scenario.